# Export timeline from Microsoft Project 2013 to Word

Tags: ms-office, ms-project

Is it possible to **export the Timeline** from a Microsoft **Project 2013** in another app such as **Microsoft Word**?
I have been able to do the same with **Project 2010**, but I cannot find any way to do so on **Project 2013**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the Timeline, or part of it, with your mouse.  Then do a ctrl-c to copy it, ctrl-v to paste into word.